# How does slot sharing help Flink?

Tags: apache-flink

Reading about Flink, what exactly are the benefits of slot sharing, for example why would I want to isolate slots in a Flink job?

My thinking is, assuming a `4GB` JVM task manager, if I seperate this into two task slots, one called `ts1` and another, `ts2`, I can put a very intensive windowing operation in `ts1` while some `map, filter` etc can go into `ts2`?

Answer (score 0):

Slot sharing means that more than one sub-task is scheduled into the same slot -- or in other words, those operator instances end up sharing resources. This has these benefits:

- Better resource utilization. Otherwise you might easily end up with some slots doing very little work, while others are quite busy.
- Reduced network traffic.
- The number of slots then ends up being the highest degree of parallelism in the job. Having each slot run one parallel slice of the job makes it easier to reason about what's happening in the runtime.

You might find it advantageous to disable slot sharing if, as you point out, you want to devote more resources to an expensive operator. On the other hand, you could keep slot sharing enabled, and give each slot more cores and/or memory.

Comment: Thanks! Whats preferable, sharing slots and having isolated slots or increasing parallelism instead with 1 slot manager a task manager?

Comment: I don't understand this question.

Comment: In terms of handling say an complicated operator, is it better to have the expensive operator in an isolated task group or have it run seperately in 100 taskamanagers with 1 task slot each/

Comment: Flink's scheduler treats all slots alike, so it doesn't make sense to have some slots that are more powerful than others.